# .htaccess in subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I read tons of topics about this here on SO, but for some reason it not works for me, and I am totally confused. I know, I mess up something, I just cant figure it what.

I have a site, and the `index.php` is calling the router, and show the content that I want.

I've created an admin' page, and I want the webserver to use the `/admin/index.php` for every request what is starting with `/admin/`

Here is what I try:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?action=$2   [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

I echoing some information from both `index.php` to see which handles my request.

If I am writing `http://localhost` it says `Frontend`.

When I try  `http://localhost/admin/` it says `Frontend` again.

If I am moving the admin' line below the first rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?action=$2   [L,NC]
```

then `http://localhost/admin/` says `Admin` what is actually good!

But if I try `http://localhost/admin/users` what is actually not there, because the admin's router should handle that, it says `Frontend`.

How should I set `.htaccess` to use `/admin/index.php` in all cases, where a `http://localhost/admin/` in the URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?action=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what does the first request rule do? Is that, "if file/dir does exist then don't actually rewrite anything"?

Comment: That means **if file/dir does exist then ignore further rules**

Comment: Thank you, it works great, I will accept it, instead, `$2` should be `$1` then.